# TSQL, how to avoid if conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am from procedure programming background, end up writing TSQL recently with my new job. My mindset still thinking about writing queries with if conditions. How to avoid following query without if condition.

```
DECLARE @NumAddress INT

SELECT 
   @NumAddress = COUNT(*) 
FROM Address
   WHERE UserID = 1001

IF @NumAddress > 0
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      u.FullName, a.Address AS Address
   FROM 
      Users u
      JOIN Address a ON a.UserID = u.UserID
   WHERE 
      u.UserId = 1000
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      u.FullName, NULL AS Address 
   FROM 
      Users u
   WHERE 
      u.UserId = 1000
END
```

NOTE: My sample query is a simplified example of my actual query. So please ignore this and provide me an example, so that how could I avoid IF conditions like this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific case, you're better off using a [`left` join](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join_left.asp):

```
select
    u.FullName,
    a.Address
from
    users u
    left join address a on
        a.userid = u.userid
where
    u.userid = 1000
```

This will return all `null` for the `address` columns if no match is found.

However, to answer your question in a more general sense, you can use a [`case` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(SQL.105).aspx) within your query to avoid having to have a whole whoopla:

```
select
    u.fullname,
    case 
        when (select count(*) from address where userid = u.userid) > 0 then 1
        else 0
    end as AddressSupplied
from
    users u
where
    userid = 1000
```

`case` is a `switch` statement in SQL, so you can do this:

```
case col_name
    when 'Val1' then 'Yup'
    when 'Val2' then 'Well...'
    when 'Val3' then 'Nope.'
    else 'What now?'
end
```

This will check the column `col_name` on each row, and if it's one of the values specified, it will return the correct `then`. Therefore, a sample query and result set is:

```
select
    col_name,
    case col_name
        when 'Val1' then 'Yup'
        when 'Val2' then 'Well...'
        when 'Val3' then 'Nope.'
        else 'What now?'
    end as some_col
from
    tableA

--------------------
col_name    some_val
--------------------
Val1        Yup
Val2        Well...
Val1        Yup
Val4        What now?
Val3        Nope.
```

This can also work in the `where` clause, which is awfully handy for semi-conditional queries:

```
where
    userid = case when @somevar > 0 then 1000 else 1001 end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the difference between 1000/1001 is a typo.  A an outer join should solve your problem.  If there are no addresses, you still get the 'FullName` with a null address.

```
   SELECT 
      u.FullName, a.Address AS Address
   FROM 
      Users u
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Address a ON a.UserID = u.UserID
   WHERE 
      u.UserId = 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

you could possibly use a left join

```
SELECT 
   u.FullName, a.Address AS Address
FROM 
   Users u
   LEFT JOIN Address a ON a.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE 
   u.UserId = 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

An outer join will do the trick.

```
SELECT u.FullName, a.Address
FROM Users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Address a ON a.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE UserId = 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course left join is right answer for this question, btw in TSQL you can use left join in more simple way, using =* , in your case

```
SELECT u.FullName, a.Address FROM Users u, Address a 
WHERE u.UserId =* a.UserId and u.UserId = 1000
```

Peoples correct me: This syntax depredecated in MSSQL (i'm think) and should be NEVER, NEVER, NEVER be used in production pjects :)

BTW, FYI you can use subselect here but it less recomeded way

```
SELECT u.FullName, (select a.Address FROM Address a where a.UserId = u.UserId) 
FROM Users u
WHERE u.UserId = 1000
```

Comment: Although you confirm the proper answer and were only trying to give alternate answers, do not ever use or even try learning about joins with _*=_, it is old style syntax.

Comment: Never use *= or =* as they do not always give correct results as sometimes SQl Server interprets as a cross join instead of an outerjoin. This is an extremely poor practice! This syntax is also being deprecated. You need to remove all of your code with it before upgrading to the next version of SQL Server.

Comment: SOmehow the * got lost in my last comment I meant Never use *= or =* not Never use = or =

Comment: 2KM and HLGEM: T-SQL is not only MSSQL lang. In Sybase this syntax isn't depredecated and recommeded even in ASE 15. i'm think, if we say about T-SQL, not about ANSI SQL, things like this every at least need to know. 
I'm affraid about depr. this syntax in MSQQL imho it more shorter and more readable then ugly 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' especially when joining 10-15 tables.
IMHO this